# Formatting text to send via email share in android app

Tags: android, email, share

I would like to send a list of  heading (from the text field) and the associated data (edit field)  in an email body via the Share button.  Ive been searching and can't seem to find much online.  Can someone tell me how I can code it?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you been searching? This is a fairly common task and I know tutorials exist. What have you tried so far? Post the code and people can show you where you are going wrong

Comment: The search words on the subject line of my issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "some@email.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text.getText().toString());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```